# How to retain the value of selected dynamic Dropdownlist for autopostback (True)? I want to implement the cascading functionality

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, c#-4.0, html

```
UI:-

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView"   OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"   runat="server"  AllowPaging="True"  OnRowCreated="onrow_databound" ShowFooter="True" AllowSorting="True"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView_SelectedIndexChanged"   GridLines="Both"    CssClass="mydatagrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pager"
    HeaderStyle-CssClass="header" RowStyle-CssClass="rows" ForeColor="#3366FF" PageSize="4"  >
               <columns>
                         <asp:TemplateField >
                         <FooterTemplate>
                              <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Insert" Height="31px"   OnClick="AddButton_Click" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="Black" BackColor="#6699FF" />

                         </FooterTemplate>

    </asp:TemplateField>
                    </columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

## aspx:- Binding the data and then creating dropdown at footer with on_row_bound for submission:

protected void onrow_databound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

```
           if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
         {

            for (int i = 1; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                TextBox txt = new TextBox();

                DropDownList dr = new DropDownList();

                    if (i == 1)
                    {
                        con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectionConn"].ConnectionString);

                        List<string> values = new List<string>();
                        string sql = @"Select spnd_type_dsc from [dbo].[proj_spnd_type]";

                        using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
                        {
                            int r = 0;

                            con.Open();


                            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                            {

                                while (reader.Read())
                                    values.Add(reader.GetString(r).TrimEnd(' '));

                            }


                            dr.ID = ID;

                            for (int j = 0; j < values.Count; j++)
                            {
                                dr.Items.Add(new ListItem(values[j]));
                            }
                            dr.AutoPostBack = false;

                            e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(dr);
                        }


                }
                    else if (i == 2)
                {

                    con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectionConn"].ConnectionString);
                    string name = dr.SelectedValue;
                    List<string> values = new List<string>();
                    string sql = @"Select [prtnr_nm] from [dbo].[proj_prtnr] j inner join [dbo].[proj_spnd_type] r on j.[spnd_ty_id] =r.[spnd_type_id] where spnd_type_dsc= '" + name + "'";

                    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
                    {
                        int r = 0;

                        con.Open();

                        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {

                            while (reader.Read())
                                values.Add(reader.GetString(r));

                        }

                        DropDownList dk = new DropDownList();
                        dk.ID = ID;
                        dk.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select--", ""));
                        for (int j = 0; j < values.Count; j++)
                        {
                            dk.Items.Add(new ListItem(values[j], values[j]));
                        }
                        dk.AutoPostBack = false;
                        e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(dk);
                    }



                }
                else if (i == 3)//Geo
                {
                    var roleList = (List<string>)Session["Geo"];
                    if (roleList.Count == 1)
                    {
                        txt.Text = roleList[0].ToString();
                        txt.Enabled = false;
                        e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(txt);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        DropDownList dd = new DropDownList();
                        dd.ID = ID;
                        dd.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select--", ""));
                        for (int j = 0; j < roleList.Count; j++)
                        {
                            dd.Items.Add(new ListItem(roleList[j], roleList[j]));
                        }
                        dd.AutoPostBack = false;
                        e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(dd);
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(txt);
                }
            }


        }

    }
```

After putting the postback in the first dropdown. I am unable to retrieve the selected value

Comment: Where are you setting ID, it looks like ID is the same for each DDL.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? How is it supposed to be assigned?

Comment: You have several lines of xx.ID = ID, but I see nowhere that ID is defined.  If its static or is set out side the loop, which I expect is the case, then the ID for each control is the same.

Comment: Even after assigning the different IDs. i'm not getting the selected value

Comment: Can you provide your updated code for the ID's as well as the code where you are trying to get the selected value?